# How to clear data grid view rows and columns except the column headers

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a quantity based information data grid view it has 3 columns of type text and 1 column of type check box, now this data grid view is filled with different item quantities and different expire dates for the same item from the inventory table whenever the user enters an item name.
The problem is whenever the item is selected and inserted in another data grid view using a button named as **Add Item** the tools used for data entry are cleared also the data grid view of quantity based information should be cleared, I tried this code but it erases the data grid view completely I just want the data retrieved from database only to be cleared and the headers of the data grid view still appear.
This codes are used in **Add Item** button

```
 DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
 r[0] = sBillItemBartxt.Text;
 r[1] = sBillItemNametxt.Text;
 r[2] = itemQuanttxt.Text;
 r[3] = itemPricetxt.Text;
 r[4] = itemTtlPricetxt.Text;
 r[5] = expire;
 dt.Rows.Add(r);
 sBilldgv.DataSource = dt;
 clearItemsText();
 sBillTtlCostlbl.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in sBilldgv.Rows where row.Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[4].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
 sBillItemBartxt.ReadOnly = sBillItemNametxt.ReadOnly = false;
 dtRes.Clear();
 exDatedgv.DataSource = null;
 exDatedgv.Rows.Clear();
 exDatedgv.Columns.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

They can be cleared nearly the same way as you add them (Without removing columns).

```
MyDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

This will target rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think your header is being cleared because of

```
exDatedgv.Columns.Clear();
```

Also if you only wish to remove the rows that are repeated, you might want to consider using a loop to check for the repeated row and remove that row only before adding a new one.
I would also tell you to use a BindingList with your datagridview but since one of your columns is a checkbox im not really sure how you could achieve this with a BindingList

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your code what you are trying to do. Since you are using as `DataTable` I am not sure why the `DataTable` `dtRes.Clear();` does not work as this will clear all the data and KEEP the column headers. When you set `exDatedgv.DataSource = null;` this will clear the rows and columns so the next two lines are superfluous. To get the `DataGridView` to clear as you describe… simply `Clear` the `DataTable` associated with that `DataGridView`. This will leave the headers intact, however after this "Clear" there will be no data in the table, so if you try to re-bind the table you just cleared, obviously it will be empty. If you do not want to remove the data from the table, then you will have to either set the headers yourself, create an empty table for this purpose or simply (not the best solution) create a copy from a master. Below I made a data bound `DataGridView`, then cleared it as described above with button 2, then re-set (re-bind) the `DataGridView` to a copy of the original table. This clears the `DataGridView` leaving the headers when pressing button 2,  then re-sets the `DataGridView` to the original data when pressing button 3. Hope this helps.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); <-- clears headers
  //dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); <-- will crash if data is bound
  //dataGridView1.DataSource = null; <-- removes headers
  dt.Clear();  // <-- Clears data and leaves headers, removes data from table!
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dt = masterTable.Copy();  // <-- Get a new table if it was cleared
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: look sir I've tried this before but what I got was after I click the button add the data inside the data grid view are still there till I enter another item in which name or barcode call the data of that item and bring it to the data grid view, what I want here is to delete the content of the data grid view and the data table together when I click add button ... in the case of using dt.Clear(); and after it  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; it clears all data and headers of columns

Comment: As you say in your previous comment:... _what I want here is to delete the content of the data grid view and the data table together when I click add button_ if you do this the headers will get deleted also. So your question is not clear.